# SDK to extract code out of .net assembly to recreate the source code?

Tags: .net, decompiling, system.reflection

Is there a SDK I can use to extract code out of .net assembly to recreate the source code?

Answer (score 0):

try using this trial version of reflector:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/